# Tomcat application slow from eclipse but quick whe tomcat is launched directly

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I configured eclipse to run my tomcat application. when launched through eclipse, the startup takes 4 minutes. instead if I copy the war file in the webapps folder of tomcat and the launch startup.bat in the tomcat bin, the startup takes only 40 seconds. What could possibly be configured wrong in eclipse?

I ran profiling and most of the time is spent in webappclassloader.getresourceasstream().

Comment: Just a wild guess : eclipse uses a lot of memory, so if you do not have enough memory, the system goes swapping.

Comment: What are the arguments of the server when launching from eclipse?

Comment: in the -vm arguments I have -Xms256m -Xmx1024m